# Location of config files when deploying Symfony

Tags: apache, symfony, symfony-3.3

I'm trying to deploy a Symfony 3 application on Kimsufi of OVH.

Everything works on my local machine, but when I deploy I get the error (debug mode is on) :

> The file "/home/remiblaiyb/app/app/config/routing.yml" does not exist.

Symfony seems to search on app/app for config, I have no idea why.

Do you have any suggestion? Thank you very much.

**EDIT**: I finally found the answer. It's due to [the new way of getting the project directory in Symfony](https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-a-simpler-way-to-get-the-project-root-directory): Symfony looks after the composer.json file, which I didn't upload in prod!

So do not forget to include your composer.json into your project.

Thanks!

Comment: Show your AppKernel.php, please.

Comment: I edited my post

Comment: Show `/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml'`

Comment: `dump($this->getRootDir().'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml')` shows `"/home/remiblaiyb/app/config/config_dev.yml"` so it's seems fine